# NRE to foreign account transfer

Tags: united-kingdom, india, non-resident, international-transfer

Can I transfer money from my Indian NRE account to my sister's savings account in UK bank?

Comment: See also this related question, [Can I transfer money from an NRE to a US checking account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29961/can-i-transfer-money-from-an-nre-account-to-a-usa-checking-account?).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can transfer to anyone. There is no restriction.